# Remove commits before specific commit

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a way to remove all commits before a specified commit and use that commit as the initial?

Comment: I know I've seen a tutorial somewhere to do something like this... It showed how you could keep a historic repo ending at commit X, and then take commit X up to HEAD and make a new repo from them, with an annotation on X about how to access the historic repo.

I can't find it right now, but it is possible.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let's say the new oldest commit's hash is X and we can use "oldroot" and "newroot" temporarily:

```
git checkout -b oldroot X
TREE=`git write-tree`
COMMIT=`echo "Killed history" | git commit-tree "$TREE"`
git checkout -b newroot "$COMMIT"
git rebase --onto newroot oldroot master
# repeat for other branches than master that should use the new initial commit
git checkout master
git branch -D oldroot
git branch -D newroot
git gc # WARNING: if everything's done right, this will actually delete your history from the repo!
```

That will create a 'newroot' commit with the same contents as the 'oldroot' commit, but without any parents.  Then, it rebases all the other branches onto the new root, which should be in the history of all of them.

EDIT: tested and fixed; slightly later, refined a bit

Comment: Note that "Killed history" becomes the new commit message for the initial commit.  If you want something else, like the original message for example, just pipe it in there.

Comment: Note that, for this to work, you have to remove your remote repo URL *prior to* running `git gc`. You can do this by: `git remote rm <remote_repo_name>` (the remote repo is typically referred to as "origin"). You can then add it back with: `git remote add <remote_repo_name> <server>`.

Answer (score 1):

The more easier solution would be,
Consider originally your branch has commit **main** and you did a commit **first**, now you also did a commit **second** on top of **first**. So you have something like:

```
main->first->second
```

Now you want to have **second** on top of **main** rather than on top of **first**. Something like:

```
main->second->first or main->second
```

You can simply do,

```
git rebase -i main
```

This will give you an interactive shell where you can rearrange the order of commits or remove any commit of your choice.