# Remove commits below a specific specific commit

Tags: git, version-control

I had pulled some project to learn something. I happen to create my work from scratch in the same project. Committed my changes on top of the existing commits. I need to remove all the commits that are below a specific commit and make it as an initial one.

The situation is something like this:

[image]

So I want to remove all commits from X till Y.

I did look into posts like [Removing commits before specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063097/remove-commits-before-specific-commit)
but could not achieve what I was looking for.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this branch public and has it been shared by anyone besides you?  You should probably _not_ rewrite the history of the branch by removing commits.  Instead, just use `git revert` to undo those earlier commits.f the

Comment: So actually, I had pulled some project to learn something. I happen to create my work from scratch in the same project. Committed my changes on top of existing commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite the whole history.

Solution 1:

```
# suppose you are now on the branch master
git checkout --orphan temp CommitY
# make the new root commit
git commit 
# apply the commits after CommitY to temp
git cherry-pick CommitY..master
# reset master to the new head
git checkout master
git reset temp --hard
git branch -D temp
```

Solution 2:

In order to demonstrate the process clearly, let's label CommitX with A and the subsequent with B, C, D(CommitY), E and F(Head).

```
git rebase -i --root
```

And then you will see the editor with contents:

```
pick 6988ba0 A
pick cd42d7a B
pick 6b1aa54 C
pick d4bc4d1 D
pick 54c78e5 E
pick fc2f728 F
```

Change `pick` of `B`, `C` and `D` to `squash` or `s`.

```
pick 6988ba0 A
s cd42d7a B
s 6b1aa54 C
s d4bc4d1 D
pick 54c78e5 E
pick fc2f728 F
```

Save and exit. Another editor with a default commit message pops up for you to input the commit message for the new root. After editing, save and exit. `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are squashed to a single commit as the new root. `E` and `F` are reapplied.

In both ways commits are rewritten/recreated， so their hashes are new. You may need to force-push to update the branch in the remote repository.